# ES6 Arrow Function. Return giving Undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, arrow-functions

I've been trying to understand arrow functions. I know that the function isValidCard is returning true however when I'm passing isValidCard to validatePayment isValidCard turns into undefined.

```
<form name="payment" action="#" onsubmit="return validatePayment();" method="post">
     <ul>
       <li><label for="cardid">Card Number *</label></li>
       <li><input type="number" name="cardid" id="cardid"></li>

       <li><label for="expiryid">Expiry Date *</label></li>
       <li><input type="number" name="expiryid" id="expiryid"></li>

       <li><label for="cvcid">CVC Number *</label></li>
       <li><input type="number" name="cvcid" id="cvcid"></li>

     </ul>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>

let validatePayment = (isValidCard, isValidExpiry, isValidCvc) => {
 validateCard();
 alert(isValidCard);
 if (!isValidCard || !isValidExpiry || !isValidCvc) {
   alert("Payment details not accepted");
   return false;
 }
 alert("Payment details accepted");
 return true;
};

let validateCard = () => {
 const card = document.payment.cardid;
 const isValidCard = card.value.length === 10;

 if (!isValidCard) {
   alert("Card Number must be 10 numbers");
 }
 return isValidCard;
};
```

Comment: Is  `isValidCard` parameter a function?

Comment: you call `validateCard();` but ignore the return value .... you don't show how you call `validatePayment` - I imagine you're probably ignoring the return value there too ... arrow functions work just like regular functions - the main difference is what `this` is (irrelevant to your code) and the fact that `arguments` is not defined inside them - again, irrelevant to your code

Comment: step one ... show how you call `validatePayment` - including what the arguments are ... then someone can show you what you're doing wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated with how I call validatePayment